# Connect to Blob storage "no credentials found for them in the configuration"

Tags: azure, databricks

I'm working with Databricks notebook backed by spark cluster. Having trouble trying to connect to the Azure blob storage. I used this [link](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html) and tried the section Access Azure Blob Storage Directly - Set up an account access key. I get no errors here:

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
  "<your-storage-account-access-key>")
```

But receive errors when I try and do an 'ls' on the directory:

```
dbutils.fs.ls("wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>")

shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Unable to access container <container name> in account <storage account name>core.windows.net using anonymous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration.
```

If there is a better way, please provide suggestion as well.  thanks

Comment: Have you "Set up a SAS for a given container" as mentioned in the doc?

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to pass the **storage account name** and **key** while setting up the configuration . You can find this from azure portal.

```py
spark.conf.set(
     "fs.azure.account.key.<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net",
     "<your-storage-account-access-key>")
```

2. Also while doing the ls you need to add
   **Container name** and **directory name.**

```
dbutils.fs.ls("wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>")
```

Hope this will resolve your issue!